# Laplace equation can implies some result

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Prove that
$$
\Delta u(x)=\Delta u(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0
$$ also implies that
$$
\Delta (|x|^{2-n}u(x/|x|^2))=0
$$ for $x/|x|^2$ in the domain of definition of $u$.
I have no idea how to start with this question. I try to calculate and simply the result of  $\Delta (|x|^{2-n}u(x/|x|^2))$ to get $0$. But I didn't get some good as we want. Hope some can get me some tips or the proof let me to reference and learn.

Comment: In polars $\Delta=r^{1-n}\partial_r r^{n-1}\partial_r+r^{-2}\Delta_{S^{n-1}}$ and so $\Delta_{(r,\vec\theta)} r^{2-n} \operatorname{id} = (1/r)^{n+2}\Delta_{(1/r,\vec\theta)}$.

Comment: Could you write it slowly? It is too fast that I am not actually understand. So we need to use the property of symmetrization, right?

Answer (score 1):

We start by recalling the Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (up to convention on sign) is:
$$
\Delta_{(r,\vec\theta)}=\underbrace{r^{1-n}\partial_r r^{n-1}\partial_r}_{=\partial_{rr}+(n-1)r^{-1}\partial_r=\text{radial part}}+\underbrace{r^{-2}\Delta_{S^{n-1}}}_{\text{spherical part}}
$$
in spherical polars.  The inversion $x\mapsto\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert^2}$ is $(r,\vec\theta)\mapsto(1/r,\vec\theta)$.

So as remarked in my comments above, it suffices (apply to $u(1/r,\vec\theta)$) to establish
$$
\Delta_{(r,\vec\theta)} r^{2-n}\operatorname{id} = \rho^{n+2}\Delta_{(\rho,\vec\theta)}
$$
where $\rho=1/r$.  The spherical part is obvious, so we just need to consider the radial part.  By the chain rule,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}r}\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}=-\rho^2\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}
$$
or equivalently
$$
r\partial_r=-\rho\partial_\rho.
$$
So the radial part of LHS is
\begin{align*}
&r^{1-n}\partial_r r^{n-1}\partial_r r^{2-n}\operatorname{id}\\
&=r^{-n}[r\partial_r r\partial_r+(2-n)r\partial_r]\operatorname{id}\\
&=\rho^n[\rho\partial_\rho \rho\partial_\rho + (n-2)\rho\partial_\rho]\operatorname{id}\\
&=\rho^{n+2}[\partial_{\rho\rho}+(n-1)\rho^{-1}\partial_\rho]\operatorname{id}
\end{align*}
which agrees with the radial part of RHS $\rho^{n+2}\Delta_{(\rho,\vec\theta)}$.  QED.

Comment: Thank you for reply.